# Counting same values in multidimensional array with unknown nesting levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to count how many (of the same) values show up in a huge list of multidimensional arrays. In the array below (a small snippet of the whole thing) I want to count how many of the "parentID" values are the same. As you can see in this example, there are 2 parent IDs with the same value. I got really close using a For loop, but since each "category detail" array has a random number of sub-arrays, i get undefined offset errors. Here is what i came close with:

```
$number_of_same = 0;
for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
    if($array['results'][$row]['categoryDetails'][$row]["parentID"]=="xID") {
        $number_of_same++;
    }
}

Array (
    [resultsTotal] => 754
    [results] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [blogComments] => 0
            [categoryDetails] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [parentId] => 1697731
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (    
            [blogComments] => 0
            [categoryDetails] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [parentId] => 1697731
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [parentId] => 1702267
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you think about Recursive way ?

Comment: I have read a lot of answers here about Recursive but none of them work. Thanks

Comment: If you have some pattern in your array then, you can use recursive way

Comment: Hey thanks for the help Sagar, you were on the right track.

Comment: congrats you have got your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `array_walk_recursive()`?

Input:

```
$array=[
    'resultsTotal'=> 754,
    'results'=> [
        [
            'blogComments'=> 0,
            'categoryDetails'=> [
                ['parentId'=> 1697731]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'blogComments'=> 0,
            'categoryDetails'=> [
                [
                    'parentId'=> 1697731
                ],
                [
                    'parentId'=> 1702267
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Method:

> **Warning**, my first posted `array_walk_recursive()` code block used `==` to identify keys called `parentId`.  This was working okay with the OP's posted sample array. However, when implemented with OP's real array, there were some unexpected key matches where keys where `0` ([Buggy Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5999753c7246e019ac94e9b944469d2dfd2f7def)).  To remedy this behavior, I simply replaced `==` with `===` and the `array_walk_recursive()` code block was back to business as normal.

```
array_walk_recursive($array,function($v,$k)use(&$result){
    if($k==='parentId'){
        if(!isset($result[$v])){$result[$v]=0;}
        ++$result[$v];
    }
}
);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1697731 => 2,
  1702267 => 1,
)
```

Explanation:

- The anonymous function call will provide both the keys and values as it traverses all "leaf nodes" (keys that have values versus arrays) of the input array.
- The `use(&$result)` makes `$result` available outside of the function since there is no `return` (`array_walk_recursive()` returns a true|false response).
- When a "leaf node" has a key that is `parentId`, then it first ensures that that key exists in the `$result` array, and then increments it.

*For speed improvements, you could try to cut down the input string to isolate only portions of your multidimensional array that *could* include `parentId` keys.

---

Here is a non-recursive method:

```
foreach(array_column($array['results'],'categoryDetails') as $details){
    foreach($details as $a){
//        if(isset($a['parentId'])){  // only use this if receiving a notice/warning - trying to access non-existent element
            if(!isset($result[$a['parentId']])){$result[$a['parentId']]=0;}
            ++$result[$a['parentId']];
//        }
    }
}
var_export($result);  // same result without any side effects
```

Comment: Mick, you rock. This stumped so many people all day, and your answer is perfect. Worked first try. Bow to Mick!

Comment: edit: caveat for anyone using this - this works amazing, beautiful. but the code i posted only had one element under [categoryDetails]. My real code has multiple elements under the [categoryDetails] leaf. This code counts all/any of the elements under. Im sure it can be narrowed down somehow.

Comment: @user3869231 Drop me a link that provides your larger array representation (please actual usable variables not a `print_r()`) and I'll see if I can help.  I think Enstage was not going down a bad path, I might prepare a method that uses some of those functions.

Comment: @user3869231 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9c446a31b5c9db6c895a461ffe3b0511f483a28